# Cakephp 1.3 helper not found in default.ctp

Tags: cakephp, view, helper

The controller

```
class PagesController extends AppController 
{
    public $helpers = array('Formatacao');
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The helper

```
class FormatacaoHelper extends AppHelper 
{
var $name = 'Formatacao';
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I'm getting this error in layout:
Undefined property:  View::$Formatacao [APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 51]

Trying to use like this: $this->Formatacao->get_clean_base_url(false);

What i'm missing?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to add the helpers to CakePHP's PagesController.

Do that in AppController instead:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
   public $helpers = array('Formatacao');
}
```

Comment: I did that, but in default.ctp I can't access $this->Formatacao.

Comment: can you post the helper class files' structure here?

Comment: Don't know why, when I call Router::url, FormatacaoHelper throws an error.
Also don't know why all erros causes allowed memory size exhausted and I can't see the real error message.

Comment: Try to check your helpers' file name and make sure it follows the CakePHP 1.3 standards. The error message clearly says Formatacao is not defined. so look into it via file name conventions.